# My eclipse wont start after installing e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, efxclipse

I installed e(fx)clipse clicked restarted eclipse for apply changing and now my eclipse wont start, it's stuck on launch with no error

though in the metadata folder there is a log that contains this

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2020-11-21 22:54:51.697
!MESSAGE Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.6.0/site/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.ui.animation_3.6.0.201907240201.jar failed on download.eclipse.org. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 11, which doesn't come with FX, so e(FX)clipse doesn't work. Change jdk.

Comment: How i can change it if I cannot even open eclipse anymore